# Error: Maximum execution time exceeded

Tags: error

I'm importing a CSV file with 112059 rows with 3 columns each.  That's 336177 entries.  I'm not a genius but I think this'll take longer than 30 seconds to process and upload this many entries to our DB.  How can I expand this timer by about... 10 times?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the **PHP script**

```
ini_set ('max_execution_time', 3000);
```

In the **.htaccess** (within the directory)

```
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
    php_value max_execution_time 3000
</IfModule>
```

In the **php.ini** (for the server)

```
max_execution_time = 3000
```

Comment: I could kiss you Pilou.